# It is possible to change how row_number inserts the values?

Tags: sql-server

Currently I'm doing this:

```
    select  
        ProductID = ProductID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCTID ORDER BY PRODUCtID),
        TransactionDate,
        TransactionAmount
    from ProductsSales
order by ProductID
```

The results are like this:

| ProductID | TransactionDate | TransactionAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-06 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-11-12 | 30 |
| 3 | 2022-11-28 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-11-03 | 10 |
| 3 | 2022-11-10 | 10 |
| 4 | 2022-11-15 | 10 |
| 3 | 2022-11-02 | 50 |

The duplicated IDs are being inserted sequential, but what I need it to be like this:

| ProductID | TransactionDate | TransactionAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-06 | 30 |
| 1.1 | 2022-11-12 | 30 |
| 1.2 | 2022-11-28 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-11-03 | 10 |
| 2.1 | 2022-11-10 | 10 |
| 2.2 | 2022-11-15 | 10 |
| 3 | 2022-11-02 | 50 |

Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide proper sample data and your complete query.

Comment: Side note: using the same column in the partition by and the order by clause is meaningless. You might as well use `order by @@spid`. Same results.

Comment: You'll have to use a different column to order those IDs. Otherwise you'll end up with unpredictable values

Comment: sorry, I have edited the post with the sample data and the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `PRODUCTID` field is numeric already, then this should work:

```
WITH _ProductIdSorted AS
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT
        (
            PRODUCTID,
            '.',
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCTID ORDER BY TransactionDate) - 1
        ) AS ProductId,
        TransactionDate,
        TransactionAmount
    FROM ProductsSales
)

SELECT
    REPLACE(ProductId, '.0', '') AS ProductId,
    TransactionDate,
    TransactionAmount
FROM _ProductIdSorted;
```

By the way, just the same as the `ORDER BY` clause in your query, the one my answer uses is a nondeterminsitic sort. It seems, based on your Post, it doesn't matter to you the order which the rows are sorted within the partition though.

Comment: This will result in essentially random (or at least unpredictable) values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct, it will, which it seems like what OP is asking for (or particularly doesn't care that they'll be nondeterminsitically ordered).

Comment: I think the OP wants something more like `CONCAT( DENSE_RANK(), '.', ROW_NUMBER() )` but without sample data, we're all just guessing.

Comment: @TimJarosz Agreed, OP should provide sample data. I'm assuming OP's table has the same `PRODUCTID` repeated already (based on the fact his `ORDER BY` uses it to nondeterminsitically sort in the window function). If it's numerical, then the single window function in my answer *should* be sufficient.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the post with the sample data and the query

Comment: @AlSimmons Does my answer solve your problem (note I updated my code to order the window function by your `TransactionDate` column to match your example)? Is the original `PRODUCTID` column, in your `ProductSales` table, a number?

Comment: @J.D. it solved partially, I need the first row to be the original ProductID, (ex: 1, 1.1, 1.2). The original ProductID is a number, I'm converting it to varchar.